Single components vs. IC Arrays
Beginner Question: I've seen boards that have 4/8/16 identical resistors in a row and boards with an IC containing the same number of resistors doing the same job. Same with diodes, transistors, and other basic components.
Why and when would I choose to use IC arrays vs. using the component singly?
These are my speculations:

It can be cheaper to buy/pick-place one IC.
It can be easier to rework/test/probe individual components.
You can save board real estate with the IC.
You can swap out a single component with the same footprint but not one member of an array.
There might be some special reason sharing a substrate is useful(?)
You can stick thermal relief on an IC more easily than a bunch of tiny components.
Your schematic is a little simpler if you use the array.

Is there more to it?

Just a note on terminology: I don't believe it's usual to call these "IC"s, I believe they are always called "arrays".

To answer your speculations:

It can be cheaper to buy/pick-place one IC.

This is conditional. If you already have a bunch of identical 100-ohm SMT resistors on your bill of materials, eight more identical resistors might be cheaper than the time/cost to add a new BOM line item, stock the part, load another reel, etc.
Even if it's a new line item, it's possible that your assembler already has a shared supply of the right discrete resistors, or the array requires special setup in the pick-and-place for centroid/rotation while the SMT resistor is handled automatically due to its highly standardized package.

It can be easier to rework/test/probe individual components. You can save board real estate with the IC. You can swap out a single component with the same footprint but not one member of an array.

These are correct (first one in my subjective experience). In the case of a single component, you also have some flexibility to fudge a different footprint for prototyping/experimentation, as long as it's "close enough" and you can make it work "well enough".
For board space, it's slightly more nuanced - trying to use an array to group eight unrelated equal-value resistors might waste a ton of space on routing.

There might be some special reason sharing a substrate is useful(?)

This is a major reason. A lot of physical integrated circuit/array fabrication processes provide really good matching between parts on the same die/substrate, but not good matching between lots or even between parts on a lot. For instance, you may get a resistor array with an absolute tolerance of 0.25%, but a 5x-better tolerance of 0.05% between resistors on the same array. The same thing happens with matched transistors, but the degree of benefit is even greater (e.g. guarantees of 100 uV typical, 400 uV maximum offset voltage, 1-4% hFE mismatch, far better than what I could do with discretes)
Additionally, by being on the same substrate, the parts are thermally bonded to each other, and their temperature (hence temperature-dependent mismatch) all track together.
This sort of matching is crucial for many precision analog circuits - in fact, I've done many designs that work under massive swings of transistor performance, as long as all of the nFETs are matched and vary together, and all of the pFETs are matched and also vary together.

You can stick thermal relief on an IC more easily than a bunch of tiny components.

Yes, but also see the note about the temperature being matched across the array (for temperature-sensitive devices)

Your schematic is a little simpler if you use the array.

Depends. If you use the array for signals that logically belong together, it's quite likely, if you use the array for unrelated signals to skimp on placements, not so much.

Is there more to it?

You've hit the major points, both technical and economical. I discussed same-substrate matching further up.
